# How can I tell when a file was compressed?

Tags: files, time, compression

I want to find out **when** my log files were compressed by `logrotate` because when I received them from `cron` in my email, the logs came in as text in the main body of the email instead.

I did:

```
ls -1la /var/log/some_services
```

And found that the logs in question are already in the compressed `.gz` format. So I was wondering if those files were emailed first, before being compressed.

However, the dates shown are not when the files were compressed, but when the logs were last updated.

How can I tell **when** a file was compressed?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. But does this really matter?

Comment: Voting to reopen as this question is not about whether a file was compressed but when it was compressed.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Did you check the answers of that question? The top-voted answer contains the answer, as far as I can see. I assume that is the reason for the closure of this question.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `file` command does **not** give the date/time when the file was compressed, but the last-modification time of the original file. So, this doesn't answer the question (which IMHO, has no answers as the information is lost / never saved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no foolproof way to tell. However, for log files, the change time (as opposed to the modification time) which you see in the output of `stat` may be the time at which the compressed file was created, because the filesystem attributes of these compressed files are rarely modified after their creation.

For `.gz` files which were *not* created by compressing an existing file, according to the [gzip file format](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#file-format), the time of compression is stored in the file itself, and you can see it in the output of the `file` command. But this will probably not be of much use to you, since your log files came from compressing existing files. In that case the time stored in the gzip file is the last modification time of the uncompressed log file, which will be before the compression occurred.

Comment: Thank you David, will accept your answer in a day's time if nobody can find a solution.